# Are there any chances that expo-location's getCurrentPositionAsync() can return cached location?

Tags: android, react-native, location-services, exp

I am using `getCurrentPositionAsync()` form `expo-location` to get user current location.

> Requests for one-time delivery of the user’s current location.
> Depending on given accuracy option it may take some time to resolve,
> especially when you’re inside a building.

As per above info from expo documentation, `getCurrentPositionAsync()` returns the current location of the user. But I have observed in my `React-Native` app that `getCurrentPositionAsync()` returns some other locations when I request for current location.

Hence, I would like to know that, Are there any chances that `getCurrentPositionAsync()` can return cached location as well?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have used getCurrentPositionAsync() with accuracy: 6 and every you request the location, expo gives you a different even if you stay in the same position. The coordenates can variate with the true coordenates for 3m, 8m and sometimes for more of 15m.

Comment: It's ok if the discrepancy is in meters. But in my case it is in kilometre. This is where I got doubt that if `getCurrentPositionAsync()` taking cache location.Are there any chances for that?

Comment: have you ever try with another device? getCurrentPositionAsync() takes the current position even if the device its offline. To me sometimes gives me a difference of more of 20m but that was because a location was null when I was trying to compare it.

Comment: Actually this is happening with three different devices and all the devices are online only.